# Connect multiple Nodejs clients to Mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I am running an app on Heroku and I want to send a notification every morning at 8. I have about 200k users and it takes a long time and slows down my app, so I would like to separate the two and keep running my API on one instance, and have a separate instance just for sending the notification in the morning.

How can I have two Nodejs servers using the same Mongodb database (and therefore the same models).

I do not understand how to connect the two instances to the same database (I am using MLab on Heroku) without copying the model schema.
Because in that case, if I modify it on one instance, I would need to do the same to the other, and it doesn't make sense to me.

I hope it is clear enough.
Thank you

Comment: Are your models set up in the same file as your mongoose connection to mlab?

Comment: You could directly make a call to the db without mongoose in this case.

Answer (score 0):

TGrif: thanks a lot, I just used MongoDB native driver, and it works. I've always used Mongoose and didnt even think about looking for alternatives.
Documentation here: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native

Thank you